# Running Totals in MS Access 2007 Query

Tags: ms-access-2007

After much searching and experimenting, I've nearly got DSUM() to work in my query although it isn't applying the criterion to the DSUM (if I remove the optional criteria then the total sum is returned; with the criterion the field stays blank).

My query 'ACTransactionViewQuery' has a column the following  DSUM:

```
DSum("[TxValue]","[ACTransactionViewQuery]","[ACT_TaxDate] <= " & 
[ACT_TaxDate]) as Balance
```

The TXValue is a calculated column, the 'domain' is the same as the current query and I'm wanting to sum transactions before or equal to the current date.

Notwithstanding that I can't get the criteria to work, I have a more general question:

Even if I get it working eventually, I intend using the query as the source for a form and applying a filter. If my limited understanding is correct, I'd expect the DSUM to return the TXValue total for all rows returned by the unfiltered domain rendering the running total useless.

Am I right? If so I'm wasting my time trying to get  the query right and might as well resort to a temp. table populated within my form. It is most vexing that it is so difficult to do in a query that which is so simple in a report!

Thanks in advance for any advice or assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate that this isn't an answer and I'd really like to know how to get this working BUT as the query runs OK without the DSUM criteria I tried filtering the results to see what happens. As expected, the running total includes all rows, not just the filtered ones. As I'll be applying a filter to the query in the form's code, it looks like I've no option but to use a temp. work table in my form. It makes things easier functionally but isn't good for performance. Thanks again anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to use a string expression for the date value:

```
DSum("[TxValue]","[ACTransactionViewQuery]","[ACT_TaxDate] <= #" & Format([ACT_TaxDate], "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#") As Balance
```

Comment: Hi Gustav. Thanks for your help although I get syntax errors using your suggested code and I've fiddled about with it to  no avail. However, as the query runs without the DSUM criteria I tried filtering the results. As expected, the running total includes all rows, not just the filtered ones. It looks like I've no option but to use a temp. work table in my form. It makes things easier functionally but isn't good for performance. Thanks again.

Comment: The expression is correct and works, so if you get a syntax error, something is spelled or typed incorrectly.

Comment: Hi Gustav. thanks. I copied & pasted the directly into the SQL and it gave me syntax errors. Perhaps it's an access version issue - I'm on ancient 2007. Not to worry,I'll fiddle about with it some more when I get time but I'm busy coding my temp work file solution at the moment. Thanks again for taking the time to look at my little problem.